# Symfony 4 - passing response to another view after form submit

Tags: php, symfony, render, symfony4

I have two methods in my symfony project. With one I am building a form which on submit needs to redirect in new view with it's response.

I keep getting an error but the wierd thing is that my response is running like it should on first method but on second I keep getting an error:

> Could not resolve argument $date of
> "App\Controller\ItController::render()", maybe you
> forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it
> with the "controller.service_arguments"?

```
public function getIt(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('startDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'data' => new \DateTime('first day of this month'),
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
        ])
        ->add(
            'save',
            SubmitType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Generate Billing Report',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn-submit btn-primary action-save']
            ]
        )
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $startDate = $data['date'];

        $this->render($date->format('Y-m-d'));


        return $this->redirectToRoute('rr');
    }

       return $this->render('details.html.twig', [
              'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);
```

And other method that needs to generate that second view with response:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="rr")
 */
public function render($date)
{
    $response = $this->someService('route/defined/from/other/external/service, $date);
    dump($response);

    return $this->render('response.html.twig', [
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

When I dump response in first method It returns it successfully but when I try to pass it on that other method it return this error. Maybe there is an option to render second view in first method?
Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  $this->render($date->format('Y-m-d')); returns a Response object but you discard it.  Then the redirect tells the browser to make a new request.  Where do you expect $date in your second method to come from?

Comment: Tha't a clue/ :) How can I pass it to other controller method? @Cerad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are redefining the `AbstractController::render` method and it calls itself with with the wrong argument type.

```
public function render($date)
{
    $response = $this->someService('route/defined/from/other/external/service', $date);
    dump($response);

    // next line calls this method that we are in App\Controller\ItController::render($date) and throws the error
    return $this->render('response.html.twig', [
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

Change that to

```
public function renderExternalResponse($date)
{
    $response = $this->someService('route/defined/from/other/external/service', $date);

    return $this->render('response.html.twig', [
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

Then change how you handle the submitted form like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    $startDate = $data['date'];

    return $this->renderExternalResponse($date->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```